# Google Cloud Identity API - missing hostname fields/data

Tags: google-api, google-workspace, google-cloud-identity

Thank you beforehand for taking the time to check out my question.

While using Cloud Identity API to query for managed devices (Windows, Mac) details from our Google Workspace, I am able to query successfully by the "device ID" assigned by google, however, the "hostname" field is not included in the response.

This is an example of the call and response that I get.

https://cloudidentity.googleapis.com/v1/devices

```py
def device_query():
    FILTER = urllib.parse.quote_plus('serial:'+<serialNumber>)
    list_url = BASE_URL + 'devices?name=' + FILTER
    auth_header = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getAuthToken()}
    content = urllib.request.urlopen(
        urllib.request.Request(list_url, headers=auth_header)).read()
    response = json.loads(content)
    deviceDetails = response['devices']
    print(deviceDetails)
```

```
{'devices':
    [{'name': 'devices/xxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'createTime': '9999-99-99T20:11:31.680Z',
      'lastSyncTime': '9999-99-99T15:01:51.922Z', 
      'ownerType': 'Company Owned',
      'model': 'Windows',
      'osVersion': 'Win10',
      'deviceType': 'Windows',
      'serialNumber': '737dh39he8d3978'}] 
}
```

When looking at any device through Workspace, I can see similar details including the hostname.

[Workspace UI device hostname example][1]

The UI URL looks like this: https://admin.google.com/ac/devices/details/8613sw4fa4-90b2-5098-61384-d139d0775r9gg/information?uid=7dhdhsw7hd3h83d&dt=4

This is the API endpoint: cloudidentity.googleapis.com/v1 I am using to retrieve device data.

Comment: can you add your code please i sending to see the request you are sending.

Comment: @DaImTo I added the code to the question details.